# "because" and "so" in same sentence

Tags: conjunctions

Will a good(Native) English speaker put "because" and "so" in one sentence?

For Example:

> **because** that apple is too heavy, **so** it fall down to the ground.

Comment: May be "it fell down"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in that sentence. Either

> The apple was too heavy so it fell down.

or

> The apple fell down because it was too heavy.

or, perhaps

> Because it was too heavy, the apple fell down.

(Though the last example places particular focus on the falling and is not so common)

There are sentences that could have both "so" and "because":

> I was so happy yesterday, because it was my birthday.
>
> Eat your broccoli because it's healthy, and so you can have dessert.

Comment: Not without changing the meaning.  It means "with the result that". It is not the same meaning as in your example.

Comment: It might be worth noting that, in _The apple was too heavy so it fell down_, the word "so" means "because", while in the sentence _I was so happy because it was my birthday_, the word "so" means "very".